# Impedir editar un Jspiner tipo date

Tags: java-swing

Puesto que podrian metrer datos no permitidos la idea es imperdir editarlo salvo por las flechas, osea no poder escribir en el.
Por mas que he buscado y probado codigos no veo como hacerlo.

```
  public GestionDeCitas() {
            initComponents();
            this.setTitle("Clínica Trassierra- Gestion de Citas de Pacientes");
            img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("imagenes/logoclinicapeq.jpg"));
            inicializarPacientes();
            cargaListaPacientes();
            inicializarMedicos();
            inicializarEspecialidades();
            cargaListaMedicos();
            SpinnerDateModel modeloSpinner  = new SpinnerDateModel();

    }
```

Eso es el constructor del jframe y aqui teneis una foto de como es el spinner

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con:

```
((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)jSFecha.getEditor()).getTextField().setEditable(false);
```

El spinner puede tener uno de varios tipos de editores, el predeterminado es tipo `JSpinner.DefaultEditor` el cual contiene un `JFormattedTextField` accesible con su respectivo getter.